# Integration of product of power and exponential functions

Tags: integration

I am trying to find a closed-form solution to

$$\int_0^\infty z^n e^{-z}e^{-az}(1-e^{-az})^{m-1}(1-az)dz=0$$

where $a$ is the variable and $m$ and $n$ are given parameters. However, I could not find a way to solve it. Could anyone help me to see whether a closed-form solution exists? Thanks a lot.

Comment: How can you find a closed form solution to an integral that equals $0$?

Comment: find an expression for $a$.

Answer (score 1):

For $m=1$, the problem is quite simple since the antiderivative expreeses in terms of the incomplete gamma function and  the integral is given by $$(a+1)^{-(n+2)}\, (1-a n)\, \Gamma (n+1)$$ provided $\Re(n)>-1\land \Re(a)>-1$.  So $a=\frac 1n$ is the solution.

The problem starts to be quite difficult even for $m=2$. Considering $I_{m,n}$, we have $$I_{2,1}=-\frac{1}{(2 a+1)^3}-\frac{1}{(a+1)^2}+\frac{2}{(a+1)^3}$$ $$I_{2,2}=\frac{-2 a \left(31 a^4+45 a^3+14 a^2-6 a-3\right) }{\left(2 a^2+3 a+1\right)^4 }$$ $$I_{2,3}=-6 \left(4 a \left(\frac{1}{(a+1)^5}-\frac{1}{(2
   a+1)^5}\right)-\frac{1}{(a+1)^4}+\frac{1}{(2 a+1)^4}\right)$$

Have fun !

Comment: Thank you. It indeed appears that a closed form solution is hard to obtain analytically when $m>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Claude Leibovici gave the value of $I_{m,n}$ for $m=1$ and some $n$-$m$-combinations. Here is the answer for integer $m>1$. The result can be obtained by rewriting $(1-\mathrm{e}^{-az})^{m-1}$ using the binomial theorem and then exchanging summation and integration.

The result is:

$$ I_{m}(a,n) = \Gamma(n+1)\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{m-1}{k}(-1)^{k} \frac{(1+a+a~k)-a(n+1)}{(1+a+a~k)^{n+2}} $$

The result seems to hold for general $m$ using the generalized binomial theorem:

$$ I(a,n,m) = \Gamma(n+1)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{m-1}{k}(-1)^{k} \frac{(1+a+a~k)-a(n+1)}{(1+a+a~k)^{n+2}} $$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This expression still does not seem to have a closed form solution ($a=1/n$ is the solution for $m=1$ but not the solution when $m>1$), but the expression is probably the easiest for obtaining a numerical solution.